# Display Date Command

Tags: shell, date

Need to export variable with date command and need the format like this

```
export etool_start=`date +"%Y%m%d%k%M
echo $etool_start
201607032314
```

This works fine when date digits are between 10-20. When the clock turns 12:00am this is where the problem comes..

```
export etool_start=`date +"%Y%m%d%k%M
echo $etool_start
20160704 014
```

I need the date to be displayed like this.

```
201607040014
```

Comment: you need to use %H instead of %k, e.g.  `date +%Y%m%d%H%M`

Comment: Yes, %H is for 24-h format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

according to `man date`

- `%k`     hour, space padded ( 0..23); same as %_H
- `-`      (hyphen) do not pad the field
- `_`      (underscore) pad with spaces
- `0`      (zero) pad with zeros

e.g. `%-H` will not pad

```
date +=%-H-
=9-
```

If you want to go to 24 hour format, with a leading 0, use `%H`.

If you prefer am/pm, you can use `%I`, you must include also `%p` to have am/pm indication.

Comment: Thanks, I did see     man but don't know how i missed this.
Thank you again